# Random Training set for GAN's

Tags: neural-network, unsupervised-learning, convolution, gan, generative-models

I have studies the gans in depth and some of its type like cycle, pix2pix, cgans. Now I want to generate random images from random distribution from generator. So I am creating a dataset with no distribution similarity between images like sky, space, designs, mobiles, and all random pictures so will generator will be able to produce random things or will it fail to understand anything ?
And what GAN's to use for this purpose ?

Comment: The only way to find out is to try it.